# Which or Who(m)?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, pronouns

Sometimes I come across "Which" being used for people.

> I didn't get to see the twins very well. That's why I can't tell *which is which.*
>
> *Which of you* ate the chocolate?
>
> *Which one* is the culprit?
>
> *Which* "you" is who? (I also didn't understand this sentence btw. I don't understand the grammar structure, nor the meaning)

But is that correct? Or I must say "Who(m)"?

Comment: It's perfectly OK to use _which_ of people when asking about the identity of one individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Which"** is used for things, children or inferior animals. Besides, "which" is used *"to mean selection"* :

e.g. A : *"I want to meet Mr. Roy."*   B: *"**Which Mr. Roy** do you want to meet?"* (Selection)

In all the examples given by you, **"which"** has been used *to show this selection* :

> "which is which", "which of you", "which one",  "which you".

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are correct.

**Which** is an interrogative pronoun.

'Which' can be used before nouns to ask questions about people. We can use 'which' when we are choosing between a small number. We know how many options there are.

Which one, Which of you, Which of them, Which of your parents, which of your sisters, Which of your teachers, Which Farukh- Farukh the banker or Farukh the teacher?